# How to debug a Windows System dll ... SSIS2008 related?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, ssis

I have a C# program which is essentially doing this:

```
private string executeSSISPackage(string PackageLocation)
{
    Package pkg;
    DTSExecResult pkgResults;
    Application app = new Application();
    using (pkg = app.LoadPackage(PackageLocation, null))
    {
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, null, null, null);
        if (pkgResults != null && pkgResults.ToString().ToLower().Equals("failure"))
        {
            //log some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The code which calls this function is starting up a new thread to call 8 (or more) SSIS packages simultaneously. The advantage to this is I can modify the SSIS packages programmatically at run time (as opposed to scheduling these SSIS packages using the windows task scheduler).

This has worked fine for quite some time, however, lately I have been seeing this scheduler program of mine crash fairly regularly. These crashes are coming from uncaught exceptions (which I am definitely TRYING to catch in a try catch inside my C# program...but alas, I just can't catch them). These uncaught exceptions are coming from OLEAUT32.dll and I cannot ascertain why. I have put an enormous amount of logging statements into the failing SSIS package but the crashes are extremely intermittent - happening on any random part of the executing package with no apparent rhyme or reason.

Is there any way I can figure out which function is failing inside the DLL? That might give me some ideas on how to proceed. Is decompiling Microsoft's DLL possible, to add additional logging statements? I'm assuming it's compiled in C or C++, so that would be a N-O, but how would I even know that from looking at the thing? Honestly, I've put as much logging as I can into my own programs and there's just nothing for me to go on.

My hunch is that because SSIS uses a "shared global memory" model to communicate to DLLs... my multi-threaded application is causing the packages to bump heads, but it's really just a theory and not something I can easily prove without more information.

I have explored all the dump files / windows event logs I can stomach and those are not getting me anywhere, either...